# how to change tabs in salesconsole

Tags: leads, calendar, sales, tab-settings

hello everyone I have the problem that in the salesconsole I have the objects as dropdown

and I need to change them to the "standard" form

change this:
[image: change]

to :
[image: to]

Comment: That's the standard menu system of console app navigation. The menu items in the list can be edited, but it sounds like you want your users to use the standard sales app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The one in **first image** is from **Lightning console app**, which is designed to work as one page application in which under one page you can open multiple primary tabs with different objects and under one primary tab you can open multiple subtabs.

The one in the **second image** is from **Lightning standard app**. In which tabs concept does not apply and you can only open one page at a time.

Both are two different apps. You cannot have Lightning Console app behave like Lightning standard app. You need to use either of them.

Answer (score 0):

In the console app the tabs will appear like this only, you can switch to standard if you require this tab set.